# Turn a returned string value into a variable

Tags: excel, vba, string, dynamic-programming

I would like to create a function that reads the number of company names in a set range and then turns each of the string values ( the names of each Company ) into Public variables so that they can then be used to create ranges across multiple functions.

I am not really sure how to go about this as I am Coding in VBA so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a dictionary or collection to hold the name as the key and the item as the range.

Comment: VBA does not have this capability - use Scott's suggestion and create a Dictionary for this.